# Curator 4.0 : Unable to take snapshot or run any action. Following examples from the document

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-curator

I am trying to take snapshot of elastic index using curator 4. (Windows machine)
Getting below error (Getting same error for all actions).

> Failed to complete action: snapshot.  : Not an IndexList object. Type:

Any idea when we get this ?
I am following the examples provided in the documentation

> https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/curator/current/snapshot.html

```
Action yaml file :
    actions:
  1:
    action: snapshot
    description: >-
      Snapshot logstash- prefixed indices older than 1 day (based on index
      creation_date) with the default snapshot name pattern of
      'curator-%Y%m%d%H%M%S'.  Wait for the snapshot to complete.  Do not skip
      the repository filesystem access check.  Use the other options to create
      the snapshot.
    options:
      repository: myrepo    
      name: shan
      ignore_unavailable: False
      include_global_state: True
      partial: False
      wait_for_completion: True
      skip_repo_fs_check: False
      timeout_override:
      continue_if_exception: False
      disable_action: False
    filters:    
    - filtertype: age
      source: creation_date
      direction: younger      
      unit: days
      unit_count: 1
      field:
      stats_result:
      epoch:
      exclude:
```

OutPut :

```
2016-07-25 22:16:40,929 INFO      Action #1: snapshot
2016-07-25 22:16:40,929 INFO      Starting new HTTP connection (1): 127.0.0.1
2016-07-25 22:16:40,944 INFO      GET http://127.0.0.1:9200/ [status:200 request:0.015s]
2016-07-25 22:16:40,946 INFO      GET http://127.0.0.1:9200/_all/_settings?expand_wildcards=open%2Cclosed [status:200 request:0.002s]
2016-07-25 22:16:40,950 INFO      GET http://127.0.0.1:9200/_cluster/state/metadata/.marvel-es-1-2016.06.27,.marvel-es-1-2016.06.28,.marvel-es-1-2016.06.29,.marvel-es-1-2016.06.30,.marvel-es-data-1,shan-claim-1 [status:200 request:0.004s]
2016-07-25 22:16:40,993 INFO      GET http://127.0.0.1:9200/.marvel-es-1-2016.06.27,.marvel-es-1-2016.06.28,.marvel-es-1-2016.06.29,.marvel-es-1-2016.06.30,.marvel-es-data-1,shan-claim-1/_stats/store,docs [status:200 request:0.042s]
2016-07-25 22:16:40,993 ERROR     Failed to complete action: snapshot.  <class 'TypeError' at 0x000000001DFCC400>: Not an IndexList object. Type: <class 'curator.indexlist.IndexList' at 0x0000000002DB39B8>.
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add another filtertype so curator knows which indexs to run against.  For example if your indexes are named logstash- your filters would look like

```
filters:
- filtertype: pattern
  kind: prefix
  value: logstash-
  exclude:
- filtertype: age
  source: creation_date
  direction: younger      
  unit: days
  unit_count: 1
  field:
  stats_result:
  epoch:
  exclude:
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a bad identation at the beginning of yourfile. The acion list should be within the "actions" keyword. This is your root level.